# Dictionary with named values?

Tags: python, data-structures, dictionary

I have a file like this :

```
A X V1
A Y V2
B X V3
B Y V4
```

Let's say the first column is a model type, second column is a version number and third is the value of something related.

I would like to answer the question : "What is the value of model A, version X ?"
For all values and all versions.

I wanted to use a dict but i only know dicts with one value for each keys. This one here needs two keys, ie something like :

```
d[model][version] = value
```

How would you do this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can *nest* dictionaries:

```
d['A'] = {}
d['A']['X'] = 'V1'
```

or you can use tuple keys instead:

```
d[('A', 'X')] = 'V1'
```

Nesting would make it easier to list all known versions for a given model:

```
versions_for_model = d['A'].keys()
```

Creating a nested dictionary setup can be simplified a little by using [`collections.defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
d = defaultdict(dict)
d['A']['X'] = 'V1'
```

Here trying to access `d['A']` automatically creates a new dictionary value.

Comment: Oh ok ! That's great ! Something tells me i should use named tuples with that ...

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("Input.txt") as inputFile:
    lines = [line.strip().split() for line in inputFile]
result = {}
for k1, k2, v in lines:
    result.setdefault(k1, {})[k2] = v
print result
```

**Output**

```
{'A': {'Y': 'V2', 'X': 'V1'}, 'B': {'Y': 'V4', 'X': 'V3'}}
```

You can access the individual elements like this

```
print result["A"]["Y"]
```

**Output**

```
V2
```

Comment: cool ! this won't work with my real file because i need to do different things for diffent lines depending on line content but i'll keep it as a reference